# Runtime Exception when using OData for Android

Tags: android, odata, runtimeexception

I am trying to build up a Android application by using OData. I only want to build up a connection to a Web Server via using OData. I am using Eclipse and it works fine outside from an Android project. However, when using an Android project the same statement rise an exception. The following statements are called:

ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc");
List listEntities = c.getEntities("Categories").execute().toList();

An instance for ODataConsumer is still created but the second statement (c.getEntities..) rises up a  run time exception. As mentioned before it works fine within a not Android project. I am using  bundle "odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar" and Android 4.1 (ADT r20).

The build path includes:
- "android.jar" for build path "Android 4.1
- odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar and android-support-v4.jar for path "Android dependencies"
nothing else.

Please, don't know what the reason for this behaviour is.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I guess it is caused by the authentication